# I can't trigger the 'click' event on jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, eventtrigger

So, I have a listener:

```
$('div#Team div.wrap ul').on('click', 'li:not(.current)', function(){
...
}
```

and

```
$('div#Team div.wrap ul li#' + hash.split("/")[1]).click();
```

but it won't trigger, I checked is the selector was garbing the correct LI, and it is grabbing the correct element.
I tried manually copy and paste'ing the code "..." onto where I call the ".click()" that isn't working *(with some minor adjustments for **$(this)**)* and id too works, but that means I have duplicated code, which I don't want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As id's have to be unique, the second selector can be shortend to `'#' + hash.split("/")[1]`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Uses arrays.

`click` will work on the *dom* object.

while `trigger('click')` will work on the *jquery object*.

```
$('div#Team div.wrap ul li#' + hash.split("/")[1])[0].click();
```

or

```
$('div#Team div.wrap ul li#' + hash.split("/")[1]).trigger('click');
```